# Android Live Wallpaper guidance

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

When it comes to making Android live wallpaper, what are the things that are exactly needed. So far I could gist as WallpaperService.Engine, SurfaceView, some major changes in Android.manifest and xml/string.xml apart from this one png drawble (i think this may be optional if i use paint).

And what else do I need to develop whole different logic for the animation to happen? is it with mathematical calculations always? I am very keen about making different kind of live wallpaper. but i am not in the right track i think.

Please suggest me some way out to right direction summarizing me what all i need so that i can make any kind of live wallpaper.

Can somebody please summarize what all is needed for live wall paper.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a different approach for live wallpaper than "normal" animation in Android.  The standard approach is to make a self-rescheduling runnable that draws to canvas.

In answer to one of your specific questions: no, you do not need to limit yourself to mathematical calculations; you can use bitmaps/sprites if you choose, but you will need to animate them yourself.

Your best place to start is the resources in the SDK:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html

Comment: do i need to know about opengl also for making live wall paper?

Comment: Most wallpaper does not use Open GL, but you may want to use it at some point.  Look here if you are interested: https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperService

Comment: the problem is i am still not able to figure out properly as to how to make a live wallpaper. I saw the cube wall paper example but if I want to make a live wall paper of water background or with a bird trees or with some globe then how do i do that?

Comment: Well, in the Cube's drawFrame routine, it calls drawCube and drawTouchPoint. Instead, you can do whatever you like using that canvas. For instance, you can draw bitmaps: you might load and scale your images in OnSurfaceChanged and then use them in drawFrame.

Comment: The first link is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Both links are dead now

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this code if You have Image path.

```
is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
bitmap.recycle();
if(imagePath!=null){
System.out.println("Hi I am try to open Bit map");
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
```

................................................. if you have image URI then use this

```
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
mImageView.setImageURI(imagepath);
```

.............. Let me know if there is any issue .

Comment: indent code 4 spaces for formatting - see `{}` button and [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Sorry .I am not understand you.

Comment: @Md Maidul Islam : I am sorry for responding to this thread so late. But the code that you have provided above basically what it does is that it takes any image either through streaming as the the first part or through any static drawable. Then set it as the wallpaper background sort of stuff right? I have not tried it but if it works then it is helpful but what exactly I was looking for was the dynamically changing sceen, like animating wall paper in our desktop.